# Kalendae js: Is there a way to automatically close the calendar once a date has be selected?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm working with Kalendae https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae and I must say it is excellent and it's great to not have to think about dependencies.

The default behaviour is that it pops up when a text box is selected and updates the date but then it requires me to click the close [x] button to close the calendar.

I'd like the calendar close upon selection of a date. I confirmed this to be the default behaviour on the Demo page as well: http://chipersoft.com/Kalendae/.

Comment: It looks like Kalendae provides some events to which I can subscribe. I may have to look in that direction.

Comment: Take a look at : https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae/issues/29

Comment: Thanks yunandtidus, that helped, I ended up doing this https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae/issues/29#issuecomment-61990192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me (unfortunately, it relies on jquery, so make sure you have jquery included):

```
ku = Kalendae.util;
$.each( $('.kalendae .k-in-month'), function(index, value) {
    ku.addEvent(value, 'click', function(event){

        this.style.display="none";
    });   
})
```

A jquery implementation was good enough for me, if you want to do it in pure javascript you'll need to replace the use of $.each and select the .kalendae elements using a pure javascript approach.

Comment: For my use case I actually had to embed the code in a window.onload call. window.onload = function() {
    /* custom code here */
   };